# how to combine this two sql into one

Tags: mysql

I'd like to combine this 2 sql into 1

```
SELECT `buy_id`,count(*) as total1 FROM `sb_offer` WHERE `offer_time`>='1563811200' AND `offer_time`<'1564416000' group by `buy_id`
```

```
SELECT `buy_id`,count(*) as total2 FROM `sb_offer` WHERE `offer_time`>='1563811200' AND `offer_time`<'1564416000' AND `is_matching`=1 group by `buy_id`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what `CASE WHEN` are for. You can use `sum` and pass 1 or 0 given your conditions.

For instance:

```sql
SELECT `buy_id`
   ,COUNT(*) AS total1 
   ,SUM(CASE WHEN `is_matching`=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS total2
FROM `sb_offer` 
WHERE 
  `offer_time`>='1563811200' 
  AND `offer_time`<'1564416000' 
GROUP BY `buy_id`
```